# RoR, Ajax, Sortable, Seralize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having just a bit of a 'duh' moment, but i have a list of menu items that i made sortable and have serialized the data using jquery ui's serialize method. I'm submitting the ajax request and and seeing the following parameters in webrick:

Parameters: `{ "sort" => "menu[]=2&menu[]=3&menu[]=1&menu[]=4" }`

Ultimately, I'd just like to have a list of `2,3,1,4` and write a sql query to update the sort_order for those items. Most of the tutorials I've found thus far have had only PHP server-side examples and people are just going `params['sort']['menu']` which returns `2,3,1,4` but in Ruby appears to return an empty object.

This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sortable").sortable({
    update : function (){ 
      $.ajax({
        type  : "POST",
        url   : "/page_parts/sort/",
        data  : {
          sort : $(".sortable").sortable('serialize')
        }
      }); 
    }   
  }); 
});
```

This is my markup:

```
<ul class="sortable">
  <% @page_parts.each do |f| %>
    <li id="menu_<%= f.id %>"><%= f.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This is my controller code:

```
def sort
  raise params['sort']['menu'].inspect
end
```

That will return:

```
Started POST "/page_parts/sort/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-12 06:19:38 -0400
  Processing by PagePartsController#sort as */*
  Parameters: {"sort"=>"menu[]=1&menu[]=2&menu[]=4&menu[]=3&menu[]=5"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

RuntimeError ("menu"):
  app/controllers/page_parts_controller.rb:9:in `sort'
```

If on the other hand i try:

```
def sort
  raise params['sort'].inspect
end
```

I get:

```
Started POST "/page_parts/sort/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-12 06:19:10 -0400
  Processing by PagePartsController#sort as */*
  Parameters: {"sort"=>"menu[]=1&menu[]=2&menu[]=3&menu[]=5&menu[]=4"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

RuntimeError ("menu[]=1&menu[]=2&menu[]=3&menu[]=5&menu[]=4"):
```

Comment: Please show us your form markup and JavaScript code. This looks like a problem on the client side. If you have `menu[]=2&menu[]=3` etc. in a querystring Rails will correctly turn it into an array (`{ "menu" => [ 2, 3, ... ] }`). What seems to be happening here is that your jQuery code is taking a querystring and putting it into a `GET` parameter called `sort` (URL-encoding it in so doing, probably).

Comment: this is the markup in gist
https://gist.github.com/1280787

Comment: ah thanks!
I knew I had to be doing something stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your problem, just as I suspected:

```
data  : {
  sort : $(".sortable").sortable('serialize'),
},
```

`serialize` returns a string like this: `menu[]=2&menu[]=3&menu[]=1&menu[]=4`. Then you're assigning that string to a property called `sort` in a new object, and giving that object as the `data` parameter. As a result what actually gets sent to the server as `POST` data that looks something like this:

```
POST /page_parts/sort/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

sort=menu%5B%5D%3D2%26menu%5B%5D%3D3%26menu%5B%5D%3D1%26menu%5B%5D%3D4
```

..which Rails (correctly) interprets as a single parameter `sort` with the decoded value `menu[]=2&menu[]=3&menu[]=1&menu[]=4`.

See where I'm going with this? Instead of taking that serialized string and setting *it* as the value of another parameter, you need to send that serialized string directly to the server *as* the `POST` data. The fix for this is easy. Change your `$.ajax` call to:

```
$.ajax(
  { type  : 'POST',
    url   : '/page_parts/sort/',
    data  : $('.sortable').sortable('serialize') // on its own, no object
  } 
);
```

This will be sent to the server like you want:

```
POST /page_parts/sort/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

menu[]=2&menu[]=3&menu[]=1&menu[]=4
```

..and Rails will receive what you expect:

```
>> params
# => { :menu => [ 2, 3, 1, 4 ] }
>> params[:menu]
# => [ 2, 3, 1, 4 ]
```